# Django debug toolbar and include in urls.py (supposedly)

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

Django 3.0.6

**Main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('{}'.format("admin/" if DEBUG else "dhjfsljdasdhje32/"), admin.site.urls), # Change admin url for security reasons.
    path('post/', include('post.urls')),
]

if DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**post.urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

**Problem**

When I try these addresses: http://localhost:8000/, http://localhost:8000/admin/, Django Debut Toolbar is showing.

**But when I try http://localhost:8000/post/1/, the debug toolbar is not showing.**

Supposedly, it has something to do with include. But I'm not sure.

Could you hep me here?

Comment: What makes you think it has something to do with include? Sometimes I have to do a hard refresh of the page to get the toolbar to show up. Check the console.log for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DetailView  template contains closing tag `</body>`? I had similar problem because one of my pages didn't has this tag.

Comment: Thank you. There was not </body>. You helped me a lot.